# Ошибка 403 при использовании прокси в IDEA

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, proxy, internet-explorer, сертификат

Имеется http прокси и сертификат, необходимый для работы через данный прокси.
Например, что бы на windows server 2016 maven смог подключиться к central репозиторию, потребовалось в файле settings.xml прописать этот прокси и данный сертификат добавить в cacert java, ссылка на которую указана в переменной среды JAVA_HOME.

Так вот, прописал прокси в параметрах Internet Explorer, и теперь куда добавить этот сертификат? Или как понять какой именно сертификат и куда добавить, чтобы, например, idea и прочие приложения смогли подключиться к интернету?

Почему-то IDEA упорно выбрасывает ошибку 403 при попытке настроить прокси.
Остальное работает, вроде, нормально.

Comment: Про какую операционную систему идет речь? И что такое IE?

Comment: @Vadik windows server 2016 и internet explorer

Comment: Я полагаю, что если сертификат еще не установлен в браузере или системе, то при попытке зайти на любой [https](https://ya.ru) сайт вы увидите предупреждение. И будет кнопка прямо в браузере по добавлению сертификата.

Comment: То же самое, например, с idea. Пропишите прокси в [настройках](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-http-proxy.html). При первом запросе в сеть idea должна будет выдать предупреждение о сертификате с возможностью его принять.

Comment: А вообще [погуглите](https://www.google.com/search?q=internet+explorer+add+certificate), в браузере должна быть возможность добавить сертификат.

Comment: Почему-то именно с IDEA какая-то беда. Выбрасывает ошибку 403.